# How to get many to many fields filter in django rest-framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to filter my data like `localhost:8000/api/1/deliveries/report/?user=1,2` Many to many field not like only one field i am trying to do but i could not please help me

Here is **`Views.py`**

```
class ReportView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Delivery.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DeliverySerializer

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]

    filter_fields = {
        'too': ['lte'],
        'fromm': ['gte'],
        'electric_bike': ['exact'],
        'mode': ['exact'],
        'user': ['exact'],

    }
```

And here is **`Serializer.py`**

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am only getting only one user filter `http://localhost:8000/api/1/deliveries/report/?user=1` like this

Comment: Its not working like this brother @JayVasant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in [django-filters documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter):

> This is a base class used for creating IN lookup filters. It is expected that this filter class is used in conjunction with another filter class, as this class only validates that the incoming value is comma-separated. The secondary filter is then used to validate the individual values.

So you should define a filter class:

```py
# filters.py

class NumberInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class ReportFilter(FilterSet):
    user = NumberInFilter(field_name='user', lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        # You should put here your existing filters
        fields = {
            'too': ['lte'],
            'fromm': ['gte'],
            'electric_bike': ['exact'],
            'mode': ['exact'],
        }
```

And then use it in your viewset:

```py
# views.py

class ReportView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Delivery.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DeliverySerializer

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ReportFilter
```

It's more flexible to use a filter class because you can implement more advanced logic and behaviour.